# 'pm2' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file error

Tags: npm-install, pm2

Here is the error message I am getting while pm2 install, tried to clean cache and also run in admin mode but no use, what could be the issue?may be having forever also install affecting it?

```
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\pm2\\package.json.3819841862',
npm ERR!   dest: 'D:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\pm2\\package.json'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator
```

.

Comment: Path variable is set to npm already

Answer (score -1):

If you have ruled out admin privilages from being the problem, then it is another program- have you tried disabling an antivirus if one is running?

After that if the issue presists, I'd go into the task manager and stop any redundant processes.

If even after that you are still having this problem, I'd reinstall pm2 globally

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).